# Coroutine awaits forever

Tags: python, python-3.4, python-asyncio

I'm using aiohttp for creating a little webapp. I have this method:

```
import logging as log

class Streamer(object):
[...]
    def _update(self, id):  # @ReservedAssignment
        loop = self.loop
        analysis_streamer = self.analysis_streamer

        analysis_streamer.runAnalyses(id, loop=loop)
        print("Analyses done")
```

and `AnalysisStreamer` has these methods:

```
class AnalysisStreamer(object):
[...]
    def runAnalyses(self, id, loop=None):
        analyses = self.queue.get(id, ())

        for analysis in analyses:
            self.runAnalysis(analysis, loop=loop)


    def runAnalysis(self, analysis, loop=None):
        log.debug("Executing {a}".format(a=analysis))
        analysis.run(loop=loop)
```

and `Analysis` has this method:

```
class Analysis(object):
    [...]

    def run(self, loop=None):
        """
        Run the analysis in a separate thread from asyncio loop

        @author Marco Sulla (marcosullaroma@gmail.com)
        @date Apr 28, 2016
        @param loop: asyncio loop to use to launch the thread. If none is 
                     provided, the default loop is used
        """

        @asyncio.coroutine
        def runInThread(self):
            # code here


        if loop is not None:
            loop.call_soon_threadsafe(
                asyncio.async,
                runInThread(self)
            )
        else:
            asyncio.async(runInThread(self))
```

and it works without problem. I tried to transform the `runAnalyses()` method in a coroutine and simply do

```
    yield from analysis_streamer.runAnalyses(id, loop=loop)
```

but this way the code does not work anymore. `_update()` will be suspended in that point and `"Analyses done"` is never printed.

PS: I'm using python 3.4.3

Comment: What does runAnalyses look like?

Comment: Added also Analysis.run code, for completeness.

Comment: Unless you make `_update` an asynchronous coroutine as well, it's being treated as a generator and `yield from` is yielding control back to `_update`'s caller.

Comment: Can you add a answer? I'll accept it.